# How to operate global variable in Spark SQL dataframe row by row sequentially on Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataset which like this:

```
+-------+------+-------+
|groupid|rownum|column2|
+-------+------+-------+
|   1   |  1   |   7   |
|   1   |  2   |   9   |
|   1   |  3   |   8   |
|   1   |  4   |   5   |
|   1   |  5   |   1   |
|   1   |  6   |   0   |
|   1   |  7   |   15  |
|   1   |  8   |   1   |
|   1   |  9   |   13  |
|   1   |  10  |   20  |
|   2   |  1   |   8   |
|   2   |  2   |   1   |
|   2   |  3   |   4   |
|   2   |  4   |   2   |
|   2   |  5   |   19  |
|   2   |  6   |   11  |
|   2   |  7   |   5   |
|   2   |  8   |   6   |
|   2   |  9   |   15  |
|   2   |  10  |   8   |
 still have more rows......
```

I want to add a new column "column3" , which if the continuous column2 values are less than 10,then they will be arranged a same number such as 1. if their appear a value larger than 10 in column2, this row will be dropped ，then the following column3 row’s value will increase 1. For example， when groupid = 1，the column3's value from rownum 1 to 6 will be 1 and the rownum7 will be dropped, the column3's value of rownum 8 will be 2 and the rownum9,10 will be dropped.After the procedure, the table will like this:

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|groupid|rownum|column2|column3|
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|   1   |  1   |   7   |   1   |
|   1   |  2   |   9   |   1   | 
|   1   |  3   |   8   |   1   |
|   1   |  4   |   5   |   1   |
|   1   |  5   |   1   |   1   |
|   1   |  6   |   0   |   1   |
|   1   |  7   |   15  |  drop | this row will be dropped, in fact not exist  
|   1   |  8   |   1   |   2   |
|   1   |  9   |   13  |  drop |  like above
|   1   |  10  |   20  |  drop |  like above
|   2   |  1   |   8   |   1   |
|   2   |  2   |   1   |   1   |
|   2   |  3   |   4   |   1   |
|   2   |  4   |   2   |   1   |
|   2   |  5   |   19  |  drop |   ...
|   2   |  6   |   11  |  drop |   ...
|   2   |  7   |   5   |   2   |
|   2   |  8   |   6   |   2   |
|   2   |  9   |   15  |  drop |   ...
|   2   |  10  |   8   |   3   |
```

In our project, the dataset is expressed as dataframe in spark sql
I try to solve this problem by udf in this way:

```scala
var last_rowNum: Int = 1
var column3_Num: Int = 1    
def assign_column3_Num(rowNum:Int): Int = {
    if (rowNum == 1){   //do nothing, just arrange 1
      column3_Num = 1
      last_rowNum = 1
      return column3_Num
    }
    /*** if the difference between rownum is 1, they have the same column3 
     * value, if not, column3_Num++, so they are different
     */ 
    if(rowNum - last_rowNum == 1){  
      last_rowNum = rowNum
      return column3_Num
    }else{
      column3_Num += 1
      last_rowNum = rowNum
      return column3_Num
    }
}
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("assign_column3_Num",assign_column3_Num _)
df.filter("column2>10")   //drop the larger rows
  .withColumn("column3",assign_column3_Num(col("column2"))) //add column3
```

as you can see, I use global variable. However, it's only effective in spark local[1] model. if i use local[8] or yarn-client, the result will totally wrong! this is because spark's running mechanism，they operate the global variable without distinguishing groupid and order!

So the question is how can i arrange right number when spark running on cluster?
use udf or udaf or RDD or other ?
thank you!

Comment: How do you get `|   2   |  10  |   8   |   3   |` in the last row of output, since you have `|   2   |  9   |   7   |` in the input

Comment: sorry, it's my problem. I've typed the wrong. and now i  correct it.@Shankar Koirala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by defining a `udf` function as below (comments are given for clarity)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def createNewCol = udf((rownum: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int], column2: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => {  // udf function
  var value = 1                                        //value for column3
  var previousValue = 0                                //value for checking condition
  var arrayBuffer = Array.empty[(Int, Int, Int)]       //initialization of array to be returned
  for((a, b) <- rownum.zip(column2)){                  //zipping the collected lists and looping
    if(b > 10 && previousValue < 10)                   //checking condition for column3
      value = value +1                                 //adding 1 for column3
    arrayBuffer = arrayBuffer ++ Array((a, b, value))  //adding the values
    previousValue = b
  }
  arrayBuffer
})
```

Now utilize the algorithm defined in the `udf` function and to get the desired result, you would need to *collect* the values of `rownum` and `column2` *grouping* them by `groupid` and *sorting* them by `rownum` and then call the `udf` function. Next steps would be to `explode` and `select` necessary columns. (commented for clarity)

```
   df.orderBy("rownum").groupBy("groupid").agg(collect_list("rownum").as("rownum"), collect_list("column2").as("column2"))  //collecting in order for generating values for column3
    .withColumn("new", createNewCol(col("rownum"), col("column2")))                      //calling udf function and storing the array of struct(rownum, column2, column3) in new column
    .drop("rownum", "column2")                                                         //droping unnecessary columns
    .withColumn("new", explode(col("new")))                                          //exploding the new column array so that each row can have struct(rownum, column2, column3)
    .select(col("groupid"), col("new._1").as("rownum"), col("new._2").as("column2"), col("new._3").as("column3"))  //selecting as separate columns
    .filter(col("column2") < 10)                                       // filtering the rows with column2 greater than 10
    .show(false)
```

You should have your desired output as

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|groupid|rownum|column2|column3|
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|1      |1     |7      |1      |
|1      |2     |9      |1      |
|1      |3     |8      |1      |
|1      |4     |5      |1      |
|1      |5     |1      |1      |
|1      |6     |0      |1      |
|1      |8     |1      |2      |
|2      |1     |8      |1      |
|2      |2     |1      |1      |
|2      |3     |4      |1      |
|2      |4     |2      |1      |
|2      |7     |5      |2      |
|2      |8     |6      |2      |
|2      |10    |8      |3      |
+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much!   You gave me a whole new idea to solve this kind of problem!  very very thanks!

Comment: great to hear that @Chuang :)